# Arduino - Sparkfun USB host

Tags: arduino, serial-port, usb

I am building a device and need to use a USB Nordic ID rfid reader. I have a Spark-fun USB host card (V9947), and now need the firmware to allow be bi directional chat in a 'rs232' style serial... just as if it were a hardware or software serial port on the Arduino.

Nordic support have reassured me that their library and examples for the Arduino are normally used with readers with RS232 ports, however the same code will work with their smaller USB device if I can overcome the USB/serial barrier.

I have the library and examples for the USB host board, but cannot determine which example code resembles my requirement requirement, I have looked through the library and found no answer there either.

This could be down to personal stupidity/ignorance... however never been this stumped before. the internet does not seem to have an answer, documentation and support for this board are at best meager.

I hope someone here has managed to solve what should be a simple mission, and I can get on with this project.

Thanks Ian

Answer (score 0):

As not knowing what you already have done, I'll make a walk through the complete setup. Please check(do) each point evenif you think its done already:

- Soldering and hardware have no shorts

  - pin headers of the shield are soldered with no shorts
  - USB Jack of Arduino is isolated on the top to prevent shorts
- With the SparkFun board, it seems like you MUST supply external power on Vin or the barrel jack. 5V from the USB cable will not work reliable.
- You must also run a jumper from pin D7 to RESET.

For the board (SparkFun DEV-09947) set up – these are mandatory pre-requirements.
Now the software

- The code/drivers you need to use for this board are on [this GitHub page](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0).
- There is a [diagnostic test](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/tree/master/examples/board_qc) which is extremely useful for checking wether your board is working correctly. Do as follows:

  - Upload this sketch to your Arduino, then open the Serial Monitor to see the diagnostic info.
  - To see the output set your Serial Monitor terminal speed to 115200
  - Plug in your hardware into the USB of the shield
  - Reset the Arduino to start the diagnostic
  - Step 1 – you’ll see it recognize the board and start a transfer test
  - Step 2 – you’ll see it attempt to test the GPIO pins – you’ll get “GPIO test failed” message. Type something in the box at the top of the Serial Monitor, then hit “Send” button and the diagnostic test will continue.
  - Step 3 – you should see it cycle through a bunch of resets, then it will attempt to detect an USB device – as we have a device plugged into the USB port on the shield you should then see some summary info with a final message of “All tests passed”
  - So **NOW we know the hardware is working** and basic software is running.
- Next step driver installation/test program for the Nordic

  - Get the [library from here](https://github.com/NordicID/nur_nurapi_micro/blob/master/arduino)
  - Import NurMicroApi_arduino.zip to IDE. From menu: Sketch->Include library->Add .ZIP library...
  - Open example. From menu: File->Examples->NurMicroApi->NurExample
  - Change baudrates and sw serial pins to match your arduino HW In this example NUR module is connected to arduino via software serial pin 10 (RX) and pin 11 (TX) with baudrate 38400. HW serial is used as print output.
- You may have to change this to the USB card connections (see diag-SW)

  - As an easier option you can use the [HID parser to check if your NUR is recognized](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/examples/HID/USBHID_desc/USBHID_desc.ino)  If that works take a working exmple like:
  - [Working HID example](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/examples/HID/USBHIDBootKbd/USBHIDBootKbd.ino) and try to read a tag then start coding with the NUR example from above if values are not correct interpreted

If you want to use the "pure" at-Terminal (RS-232) style you have to get rid of the usb shields functions (lib) and write your own Arduino firmware based (=overcome the USB/serial barrier) on the nordic-api (well documented) Hope this gets you started

Comment: Hi Codebreaker, back on the arduino/NUR tag project.

Comment: I followed your detailed steps, even though I had got the basic h/w & s/w working, never hurts!

Comment: it is in the second section where I hit the issue, using NURexample I changed the baud rate to 115200 - the default for the Nordic... and uploaded the code. I get a message 'start' then this is followed with 'NUR NOT DETECTED', then 'ERROR'. This is where my understanding is totally lacking!  Has the USB port created a software serial at arduino pins 10&11?

Comment: No the usb port should be a transparent piece of hardware for the Arduino program. So as I wrote: You may have to change this (the pins of Software Serial) to the USB card connections (see result of diag-SW) .

Comment: OK, I think I don't know what you mean diag-SW.. Sorry for being thick, and you patience is appreciated!

Comment: In my answer "Now the software => step  2" - save the results and check if the output of the diag matches your code settings

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer